# joomla 2.5 translate jtext form administrator

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, translation

I have installed `joomla! 2.5` and i'm using **JTEXT** for translation. I'm working with files directly. 
how can i translate **JTEXT** files from admin interface  ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

> Extensions -> Language Manager -> Overrides -> New

There is a search function that you could search for the text you want to translate and get the appropriate variable.

Good Luck!